# how to use IN cluse in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Sql query as follow, please help me  how write the exact query in Linq.  thanks

```
select count(ExpiredProjectID) from AssignedExpiredProjects where ExpiredProjectID IN (select id from ExpiredProjectsTracking)
```

Comment: Show us a sample code you've tried

Comment: var assinged = from t1 in db.AssignedExProjects
                           from t2 in db.ExpiredProjectsTracking
               where t1.ExpiredProjectID.Contains(t2.ID)
               select t1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code......

```
var projIDs= (from ept in _context.ExpiredProjectsTracking
              select ept.id).ToList();

int resultCount= (from apt in _context.AssignedExpiredProjects
                  where projIDs.Contains(apt.ExpiredProjectID)
                  select apt.ExpiredProjectID).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchList = context.ExpiredProjectsTracking.ToList();

var sum = context.AssignedExpiredProjects.Count(x => searchList.Contains(x.Id))
```

Comment: it says CMIS.Model.AssignedExpiredProjects does not contains a difination for count